# TypeError: arrayObject.sort is not a function in react jest enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to write assertion for a menu list which render after full fill the expression condition and sorted such as:

```
{packageFamilyId && 
packageMap[packageFamilyId] && 
packageMap[packageFamilyId].sort(Constants.sortAlphabeticallyAscending)
.map((p) => (
<MenuItem value={p.id} key={p.id} data-test="package-menu">{p.name}</MenuItem>
}
```

I am passing props as:

```
const props = {
packageFamilyId: 1,
      packageMap: [
        {
          packageFamilyId: [],
        },
        {
          packageFamilyId: [
            {
              active: true,
              code: "0",
              id: 121,
              is_price_applicable: false,
              name: "ctest_name",
              typeId: 2,
            },
 {
              active: true,
              code: "0",
              id: 121,
              is_price_applicable: false,
              name: "btest_name",
              typeId: 2,
            },
 {
              active: true,
              code: "0",
              id: 121,
              is_price_applicable: false,
              name: "atest_name",
              typeId: 2,
            }
          ],
        },
      ],
};
```

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import { componentName } from "./componentName ";
import componentNameMock from "../../../test/mockData/componentName";

describe("componentNameComponent", () => {
const wrapper = shallow(<component {...props} />);
const menuList = wrapper.find("[data-test='package-menu']");
expect(menuList .length()).toEqual(1);
});
```

But it is giving me Type Error:
TypeError: packageMap[packageFamilyId].sort is not a function

```
             packageMap[packageFamilyId] &&
             packageMap[packageFamilyId]
                 .sort(Constants.sortAlphabeticallyAscending)
```

............................................................................
where Constants.sortAlphabeticallyAscending  is sorting function

```
sortAlphabeticallyAscending: (a, b) => { 
if (a !== undefined && b !== undefined) {
if (a.name?.toLowerCase() < b.name?.toLowerCase()) return -1;
else if (a.name?.toLowerCase() > b.name?.toLowerCase()) return 1;
else return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: `packageFamilyId` is `1` but you have only one item in the array so `sort()` is not a function of `undefined`

Comment: thanks for response, edited the code , it doesn't have impact of it, it sort the object list by name , can check the edit code , error still the same

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

`packageMap[packageFamilyId]` is an object:

```
{
  packageFamilyId: [
    {
      active: true,
      code: "0",
      id: 121,
      is_price_applicable: false,
      name: "ctest_name",
      typeId: 2,
    },
    {
      active: true,
      code: "0",
      id: 121,
      is_price_applicable: false,
      name: "btest_name",
      typeId: 2,
    },
    {
      active: true,
      code: "0",
      id: 121,
      is_price_applicable: false,
      name: "atest_name",
      typeId: 2,
    }
  ],
}
```

This is not an array nor is there a `sort` property that is a function that can be called. In otherwords, `packageMap[packageFamilyId].sort` is undefined and not callable.

## Solution

Access the property that ***is*** an array and sort this.

```
{packageMap[packageFamilyId]?.packageFamilyId?.sort(
    Constants.sortAlphabeticallyAscending
  ).map((p) => (
    <MenuItem value={p.id} key={p.id} data-test="package-menu">
      {p.name}
    </MenuItem>
  )
)}
```

Since there are actually 3 elements in the specified array the test should be updated to assert against the correct length. `length` is also a property, not a function to call.

```
describe("componentNameComponent", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<component {...props} />);
  const menuList = wrapper.find("[data-test='package-menu']");
  expect(menuList.length).toEqual(3);
});
```

Comment: thanks buddy , you got a nice catch. didn't noticed the silly mistake here.

Answer (score 0):

it worked with mockup setting , instead of familyPackageId string i gave value 1(index value).

```
 it("expects to render package-menu ", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<componentNameComponent{...props} />);
    const menuList = wrapper.find("[data-test='package-menu']");
    expect(menuList .length).toEqual(props.packageMap["1"].length);
  });
```

```
packageMap: {
    1: [
      {
        id: 4,
        isPriceApplicable: true,
        is_price_applicable: true,
        name: "ctest_name",
        packageAgentType: "FoS",
        typeId: 1,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        isPriceApplicable: true,
        is_price_applicable: true,
        name: "btest_name",
        packageAgentType: "FoS",
        typeId: 1,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        isPriceApplicable: true,
        is_price_applicable: true,
        name: "atest_name",
        packageAgentType: "FoS",
        typeId: 1,
      },
    ],
  },
```